# VB6 control iteration: one control gives me an error; which one?

Tags: vb6

I am trying to loop through all controls in a form:
For Each ctrl in Me.Controls
in order enable/disable the control based on some conditions.
But there is a control on the form that gives an error when I try to access it. What kind of control does that, and how do I find it?

Answer (score 1):

When you get your error and click Debug, is the error on the line setting a control's Enabled property?

If so, add a Debug.Print statement writing out the control's name.  Do so on the line before setting the Enabled property.

Here's what I mean:

```
Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    Debug.Print ctrl.Name
    ctrl.Enabled = True      
Next
```

The Debug.Print statement will write out to the Immediate Window the name of the control that was last processed in the loop, presumably the one that caused your error.

**EDIT**

This *might* work.  Put this control in a Panel control and set the Panel's Enabled property to False.  If I recall correctly, in VB6 setting a container control's Enabled property to False will also set the container's child controls Enabled to False.  If your control's Enabled property really is read-only, I'm curious what would happen.

Comment: The when trying to access this ctrl (as in looping through all controls to debug.print them), a popup box saying the "Property is write only" when this particular control is encountered.

Comment: The error you describe is when you're trying to set the Enabled property of the control that's giving you problems?  What kind of control is it?  Is there an Enabled property that you can set for the control when you're viewing your form in the designer?  It's possible that the control's Enabled property is read only - that is what the error message you're setting is saying.  See my edit for another idea that may work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim ctr As Control
Dim CtrStatus Boolean

CtrStatus = False

For Each ctr In Me.Controls

  If (SSTab.hwnd = GetParent(ctr.hwnd)) Then
    Call CallByName(ctr, "Enabled", VbLet, CtrStatus)
  else
    ctr.Enabled = CtrStatus
  End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is as follows, that also works at runtime (as opposed to just in the IDE):

```
private sub SetEnabled()
  on error goto errHandle

  Dim ctrl As Control
  For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    ctrl.Enabled = True      
  Next

  exitPoint:
    exit sub
  errHandle:
    MsgBox "Error " & err.Description & " with Control " & ctrl.Name
    resume exitPoint
end sub
```

Comment: It's crapping out on SSTab. I'm checking if the control's container is a certain frame, then enable/disable it..."If ctrl.Container = fraMovies Then...". But when the program loops and tries to check SSTab's container it throws an exception.

Comment: I am guessing that SSTab does not have an Enabled property.

Comment: @AngryHacker: at first I also thought SSTab must not have an Enabled property: but `tosa`'s problem code line is **not using the Enabled property**. See my answer for my take on the problem (= not Is). Your answer is a good one give the original question, which strongly implies that the problem happens when changing the Enabled property, rather than trying to establish the control's Container.

Answer (score 0):

Tosa: from your comment on [AngryHacker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645734/vb6-control-iteration-one-control-gives-me-an-error-which-one/1646974#1646974), I think you are checking the container incorrectly.

Your code is like this

```
 ' BAD CODE '
 If ctrl.Container = fraMovies Then
```

For me that gives error 450 `Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`. Do you get the same error?

The code should use `Is` rather than `=`, like this

```
 ' GOOD CODE '
 If ctrl.Container Is fraMovies Then
```

**Explanation.** You want to check whether two variables "point" to the same control. Controls are objects: [you must use `Is` not `=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242809(VS.60).aspx) to check whether two object variables "point" to the same object. This is a classic pitfall in VB6.

**One last word.** Next time, could you try to post 10 lines or less of actual code, reproducing the error, and give the exact error number and message and the exact line on which it occurs? It really does make it much easier for us to solve your problem - I know it's work for you to shorten the code, but you'll get better answers that way.

**EDIT** Welcome back! :) You said some controls don't have a Container property. You could try wrapping the test in `On Error Resume Next`, something like this.

```
 ' GOOD CODE '
 Dim bMatch As Boolean  
 Dim ctrl As Control 
 For Each ctrl In Me.Controls 
   bMatch = False  
   On Error Resume Next  
   bMatch = (ctrl.Container Is fraMovies)  
   On Error Goto 0 
   If bMatch Then  
     ctrl.Enabled = True       
   End If
 Next
```

Comment: Hello, I'm back looking at this issue. Thanks, the "is" works. Now the problem is at the .container check portion. There are controls that don't have a container (such as commondialog), and checking them for a container gives an error. What I am trying to do is loop through all the objects in a frame and disable them. This should also be the case for and objects in frames that are in the original frame (iterative loop). What's the best way for this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Instead of continuing processing at the next line (via On Error Resume Next, how do I instead go to the next object in the For Each loop? The problem is that even though some controls don't have containers, they do have an enabled property, and thus they get disabled/enabled on the resume part. Better yet, how do I check if an object has a container property (without using an error catcher)?

Comment: Hi, there's no `Cycle` statement in VB6 that allows you to go straight to the next object. My suggestion is to use an `If` block to wrap the use of the Enabled property. I'll edit my answer again to make that plainer. I don't think there's any simpler way to detect whether an object has a container property other than using an error trap.

Answer (score 0):

Suppress the error reports before the loop and then set it back to standard error handling:

```
On Error Resume Next
 For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
      ctrl.Enabled = lIsEnabled
 Next
 On Error GoTo 0
```

OR name your controls with a standard prefix/suffix that you can check by name and skip in the loop.

```
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
      If Left(ctrl.Name, 3) = "sst" Then
           ctrl.Enabled = lIsEnabled
      End If
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such problems follow the given rules while naming contols

- When you name an element in your Visual Basic application, **the first character of that name must be an alphabetic character or an underscore.**
- **Begin each separate word in a name with a capital letter, as in FindLastRecord and RedrawMyForm.
- Begin function and method names with a verb, as in InitNameArray or CloseDialog.
  Begin class, structure, module, and property names with a noun, as in EmployeeName or CarAccessory.
- Begin interface names with the prefix "I", followed by a noun or a noun phrase, like IComponent, or with an adjective describing the interface's behavior, like IPersistable. Do not use the underscore, and use abbreviations sparingly, because abbreviations can cause confusion.
- Begin event handler names with a noun describing the type of event followed by the "EventHandler" suffix, as in "MouseEventHandler".
- In names of event argument classes, include the "EventArgs" suffix.
  If an event has a concept of "before" or "after," use a suffix in present or past tense, as in "ControlAdd" or "ControlAdded".
- For long or frequently used terms, use abbreviations to keep name lengths reasonable, for example, "HTML", instead of "Hypertext Markup Language". In general, variable names greater than 32 characters are difficult to read on a monitor set to a low resolution. Also, make sure your abbreviations are consistent throughout the entire application. Randomly switching in a project between "HTML" and "Hypertext Markup Language" can lead to confusion.
- Avoid using names in an inner scope that are the same as names in an outer scope. Errors can result if the wrong variable is accessed. If a conflict occurs between a variable and the keyword of the same name, you must identify the keyword by preceding it with the appropriate type library. **For example, if you have a variable called Date, you can use the intrinsic Date function only by calling DateTime.Date.**